# How to trigger validations check conditionally in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-validation, angular-validator

I have an `Angular 8` app. It has a form that captures a movie & tickets.

Model Definition

```
export class Movie
{
  name:string;
}

export class Ticket
{
   name:string;
   price:number;
}
```

Using Reactive Form to build the form as below.

```
  public buildForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.form = this.fb.group({
        /* primary */
        'name': ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        /* tickets*/
        'tickets': this.fb.array([this.buidTicketForm()])
    })
  }

  public buidTicketForm(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
        'name': ['',[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
        'price': [0.00,[Validators.required, Validators.min(0.00)]],
    })
}
```

Now my requirement is the validations associated with the ticket should trigger conditionally.

*As if the ticket validations should run **only** if the ticketName is not null else no need to check for validations.*

Thanks!

Comment: You can use setValidators([Validators.required]) method on condition. Please refer this blog :: https://www.codementor.io/jimohhadi/angular-validators-with-conditional-validation-in-reactive-forms-pj5z7gsq5

Answer (score 0):

You can either build [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators) or make conditional method like below:

```
  private setValidators(formKey: string) {
    if (this.form.get('name').value !== null) {
      return [
        Validators.required,
        formKey === 'name' ? Validators.minLength(3) : Validators.min(0.00)
      ];
    }
```

Next apply it on your form builder:

```
public buidTicketForm(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
      'name': ['',this.setValidators('name')],
      'price': [0.00,this.setValidators('price')],
  });
}
```